# ng-app not always starting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started having problems in my new project, where I'm using angular apps in pyramid served jinja2 templates.

One template has DIV with *ng-app* that starts working only sometimes. I tried with simple module with one controller that only logs "I'm here!" into console, but it worked only sometimes (I'm 100% sure template was rendered correcly).

My workaround for this problem is to use *ng-app* tag and to use *angular.bootstrap* at the same time, which sometimes generates errors, but makes app work. For whatever reason just using *angular.bootstrap* does not always work.

Am I missing something here?

```js
var ticketApp = angular.module('ticketApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

ticketApp.factory('ticketAppData', function() {
    var all_ticket_data = {};
    return {all_ticket_data: all_ticket_data};
});

ticketApp.controller('TicketAppController', function($scope, ticketAppData) {
});

ticketApp.controller('TicketAppListController', function($scope, ticketAppData) {
    $scope.data = ticketAppData;
});

ticketApp.controller('TicketAppDetailsController', function($scope, ticketAppData) {
    $scope.data = ticketAppData;
});

ticketApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/list', {
            templateUrl: '/static/ticket-ng-app/views/list.html',
            controller: 'TicketAppListController'
        }).
        when('/details/:ticket_id', {
            templateUrl: '/static/ticket-ng-app/views/details.html',
            controller: 'TicketAppDetailsController'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/list'
        });
    }
]);

angular.bootstrap($('#ticketApp-window'), ['ticketApp']);
```

```html
<div id="ticketApp-window" ng-app="ticketApp" ng-controller="TicketAppController">
  <div ng-view class="ticket-app-view"></div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../static/ticket-ng-app/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've noticed something similar in my weather application, it throws a bunch of errors the first time I open the application saying that it can't load angular. Then I wait a few minutes and refresh, and it works. Not sure what the cause might be.

Comment: I'm starting to think AngularJS Batarang has something to do with this problem.

Comment: I had looks like same issue, sometimes ng app was not started (Chrome), any JS error in console. When i remove Batarang, problem disappear ...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ng-app, putting the controller on the ng-view and calling angular.bootstrap like this:

```
var ticketAppWin = document.getElementById('ticketApp-window');
angular.bootstrap(angular.element(ticketAppWin), ['ticketApp']);
```

It's better to let angular.element wrap up the DOMElement than doing it yourself.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u78meq8g/